# Best way to store collection of primitive datatypes in Entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I am using EF code first as an ORM techniques for my project where Domain model has so many collection of primitive datatypes.
**What are possible solutions for storing the collection of primitive datatypes and which is the best solution**

**Solutions I know are as following:**

1.**Create a different class which will hold the the property of that primitive datatype whose collection we want to use and instead of directly using the collection of that primitive type use the collection of newly created class, **better explanation for this scenario is****

[Entity Framework Code First primitive collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236630/entity-framework-code-first-primitive-collections)

2.Serialize the list of primitive dataype in a single coloumn and use some seperator for extracting the items and wrote your own logic for saving the list of primitive datatype as a single coloumn and use logic for parsing the received database value to back to the respective datatype collection.

So, above two are known solutions to me But i want to know which is the best solutions for storing collection of primitive datatypes

Comment: do you need to query them - or just load/save once. How big the list is etc. That's what you should be looking at. It all depends on the case at hand.

Answer (score 2):

After reading and trying out so many options, I have found that 
both of above strategies increase complexity, data retrieval and saving.

So, the best approach (in my opinion) is to serialize the collection of primitive datatypes as a byte array in the database and deserialize the data database:

```
Class Sample
{
    [NotMapped]
    Public List<String>Strings { get; set; }

    Public Byte[] StringBytes
    {
        get
        {
            var binaryfomrate = new BinaryFormatter();

            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            binaryFormatter.searilze(ms, this.Strings);

            return ms.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            var binaryfomrater = new BinaryFormatter();
            this.Strings = binaryFormtter.Deserialize(value) as List<String>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first solution is best way for storing collection type in database. In other word you must define a class for your primitive type then make a relation between two classes.